# Sending an Array of Objects to a component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm a begginer in web development and i'm trying to make a front end using vuejs and vuetify.
My problem is that i can't figure out why I can't pass an array of objects to a component.

My code is the following :

In my main page i got these lines to use the component :

```
<template>
   ...
   <v-content>
      ...
      <list-2 :objectsProps="clients"/>
      ...
   </v-content>
   ...
</template>

-----------------------
<script>
import List2 from "./components/List2";


export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    List2
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      clients: [],
      ...
    };
  },
  ...
  mounted() {
    this.clients = [
      {
        title: "Client1",
        description: "Unknown"
      },
      {
        title: "Client2",
        description: "Unknown"
      },
      {
        title: "Pradier",
        description: "Unknown"
      }
    ];
  }
};
</script>
```

And my component is like that:

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-list two-line subheader>
            <v-subheader>List</v-subheader>

            <v-list-tile v-for="object in objects" :key="object.title" avatar>
                <v-list-tile-avatar>
                    <v-icon x-large>account_circle</v-icon>
                </v-list-tile-avatar>

                <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{ object.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                    <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{ object.description }}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>

                <v-list-tile-action>
                </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-card>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "List2",
  props: {
    objectsProps: []
  },
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed:{
      objects: function(){
          return this.objectsProps
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

At this point, i don't have enough knowledge on vue to understand what is exactly going on here, but what i'm trying to do is to give a list of objects (which can be a list of clients or a list of vehicles or anything) to my component.

The List2 component shouldn't be aware of what it is displaying as long as it gets some objects with a title and a description.

I use a computed property on the component, because i don't know if it's recommended to do a v-for on the props.

And I constantly get this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at render (vuetify.js:7048)
    at createFunctionalComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4056)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4246)
    at _createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js:4416)
    at createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js:4353)
    at vm._c (vue.runtime.esm.js:4485)
    at List2.vue?36c9:37
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.runtime.esm.js:3701)
    at Proxy.render (List2.vue?36c9:13)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:4540)
```

Along with these warnings :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "objectsProps". Expected , got Array.

found in

---> <List2> at src/components/List2.vue
       <VContent>
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
vue.runtime.esm.js:587 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

found in

---> <List2> at src/components/List2.vue
       <VContent>
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

But i have no filter property in my main page or my component, so i don't get why...

So my question are : Is my approach correct, or am i doing it the wrong way?
What should I do to in order to make it work ?

And if you have some tips/advices for a beginner, i'm definetly up to get them ! 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this empty section in my list :

```
<v-list-tile-action>
</v-list-tile-action>
```

And that was causing the filter error, i just had to delete it, thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define your property with a default value

```
props: {
    objectsProps: {
        type: Array,
        default() {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

BTW:

> I use a computed property on the component, because i don't know if it's recommended to do a v-for on the props.

No need for a computed property

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer ! :)
It seems to work properly without the computed property and the default value.

My objectProps is still well filled :
[{"title":"Client1","description":"Unknowm"},
{"title":"Client2","d...

But i still got the error :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

and the warning :
"[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

I had this error in a previous component (it was named List1) and i have the feeling that this error is still here because of that past component that I don't use anymore.

Comment: That error is from the vuetify.js library, and it is in reference to `List2`; but there's not enough information in the original post to diagnose any further.

Comment: If you want the sources are available here : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NVibNFYE3J7udIMLjqW7rvohNbaGG1MZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

#### This is what's happening in your code...

Vue allows specifying a `prop` of a [specific data type](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) like this:

```
props: {
  foo: String
}
```

or with *multiple* valid types like this:

```
props: {
  foo: [String, Number] // foo can be a `String` or a `Number`
}
```

The type array (`[String, Number]` in the example above) should not be empty:

```
props: {
  foo: [] // invalid: missing types
}
```

#### This is how to fix it...

If you were attempting to enable type checking for the `prop` so that Vue enforced values of type `Array`, the correct syntax would be:

```
props: {
  foo: Array
}
```

Or if you were trying to specify an empty array as the default `prop` value:

```
props: {
  foo: {
    default: () => []
  }
}
```

You could even do both:

```
props: {
  foo: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y99oj6464?module=src/components/MyList.vue)

> But i have no filter property in my main page or my component, so i don't get why...

Although I wasn't able to reproduce that error with the code shown in question, I'm guessing you have a third-party library/component that perhaps uses [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your array `prop`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking time to answer me, my code looks cleaner thanks to you. :)

Comment: @FaureUgo No problem :)

Comment: But I still have this "filter" error and I think that you might be right by saying that a library uses Array#Filter. Earlier I imported Lodash in my project to be able to filter the lists in my components. 

But now i'm not using it anymore, do you have any clue on how to fix this ?

Comment: Not without seeing the actual code. Can you ask a new question with a fiddle (or GitHub repo link) to reproduce the problem? That would allow others to provide more detailed answers that could be helpful.

Comment: When i try to copy/paste my code in a sandbox it actually works as we can see here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/w053r6m91l

If you want, the sources without the node_modules are available here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NVibNFYE3J7udIMLjqW7rvohNbaGG1MZ/view?usp=sharing